Jekyll theme Documentation gets the date wrong on github pages
I am using the Documentation theme on github pages. It has been working fine for several years.
Today I wrote a new post (a news item). I use a localhost development site to preview things and the post appeared on that, however, it did not appear on github pages when I pushed to the repository.
The markdown source file for the post was present in the repository but a corresponding HTML file was not built.
After a little experimentation, I discovered that the problem is caused by the date. The markdown file name begins with the date (YYYY-MM-DD) followed by a post title. If I changed the file name year to 2023 then the item appeared on github pages.
Interestingly, the Documentation theme has a news_archive.html page, which showed the 2023 news items under the heading "This year's posts". On my own machine, "This year's posts"  correctly heads up 2024 posts.
So, somehow, the date is wrong when the site builds on github. I have no idea how to try to fix this (is it even my problem?).
For now, I have now inserted future: true in the _config.yml file. This allows future posts to be displayed and now shows news archive correctly with the post belonging to this year.
I am at a loss. Should I report this to github support?

"Should I report this to github support?"... yes

The problem arose because of timezone differences. I was working in a timezone about half a day ahead of GMT. This had not been a problem in the past because I would have posted in the afternoon, but in the morning my date is different from GMT.
There is a timezone configuration option for jeykll. Once this option is correctly set in _config.yml, posting behaves as expected.
